# How to create a custom List with several columns from a Loop

Tags: xamarin.android

I need to create a custom List by looping through two sets of data. Below is what I am using but when I attach it to my listview I'm only getting the last record. I tried moving the this.CoeListitem = New List which I know is the problem to above the first loop but that didn't return any records. So how do I set this up to create my List with the correct number of records. 
Here is my

```
  public class CoeList

[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
public long Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string CreateDt { get; set; }
```

Here are my loops, the first is to get my Coe Items and the second is to get all the adults that go to each Coe item which could be many which is why I need two loops.

```
        //new loop
    List<Coe> allCoe = (List<Coe>)((OmsisMobileApplication)Application).OmsisRepository.GetAllCoe();
    if (allCoe.Count > 0)
    {
      foreach (var Coeitem in allCoe)
      {
      //take the coe id and get the adults
        List<Adult> AdultsList = (List<Adult>)((OmsisMobileApplication)Application).OmsisRepository.GetAdultByCoeMID(Coeitem.Id);
        if (AdultsList.Count > 0)
        {
          foreach (var AdltItem in AdultsList)
          {
            CoeNames += "; " + AdltItem.LName + ", " + AdltItem.FName;
          }
        }
          CoeNames = CoeNames.Substring(1);
          //ceate new list for coelist
          this.CoeListitem = new List<CoeList>()
            {
              new CoeList() { Id = Coeitem.Id, CreateDt = Coeitem.CreateDt, Name = CoeNames }
            };
      }
    }
  // End loop
  _list.Adapter = new CoeListAdapter(this, CoeListitem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies with the fact that with each iteration of the loop you are recreating the entire list and loosing  all prior items (You assign a **new** list, with only one item, to the variable). Thus at the end of the loop you have only one item.

You must create a list *outside* the loop and only add each item to the list in the lop body.

```
// create the new list first
this.CoeListitem = new List<CoeList>();

var application = (OmsisMobileApplication) Application;
List<Coe> allCoe = (List<Coe>) application.OmsisRepository.GetAllCoe();
foreach (var Coeitem in allCoe) //new loop
{
    //take the coe id and get the adults
    List<Adult> AdultsList = (List<Adult>) application.OmsisRepository.GetAdultByCoeMID(Coeitem.Id);
    foreach (var AdltItem in AdultsList)
    {
        CoeNames += "; " + AdltItem.LName + ", " + AdltItem.FName;
    }
    CoeNames = CoeNames.Substring(1);

    // Add the item to the existing list
    this.CoeListitem.Add(new CoeList { Id = Coeitem.Id, CreateDt = Coeitem.CreateDt, Name = CoeNames });
} // End loop

// give the list to the adapter
_list.Adapter = new CoeListAdapter(this, CoeListitem);
```

Hope this helps.